# Error during compilation [ReflectionException] M2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1

relatively new install of M2.1.7, getting a compilation error which is preventing setup:di:compile and switching between production/developer mode. Any ideas? Can't seem to find much... Thanks in advance

[image]

---

Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 38 secs 230.0 MiBMiB

[ReflectionException]
  Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache does not exist

[ReflectionException]
  Class Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache does not exist

setup:di:compile

---

Comment: Hi@Ben,Is there any Custom 'Doctrine' named module in your magento

Comment: hi @shivashankarm - thanks for the response, brilliant! yes I believe it was something to do with our stripe payment module.